# Pattern matching tagged union types

Tags: elm, algebraic-data-types

I have a tagged union type that contains some record data, like

```
type Comment = New Content | Edited Content | Flagged Content

type alias Content = {id: Int, text: String}
```

where the `Comment` type declares the state.

When using pattern matching for example to filter by id, I have to write

```
filter Int -> Comment -> Bool
filter id comment =
  case comment of
    New content -> content.id == id
    Edited content -> content.id == id
    Flagged content -> content.id = id
```

This works, but I have to duplicate the same logic for each case, when instead I'd like it simple as

```
 filter id comment =
   case comment of
     _ content -> content.id == id
```

With function such as the filtering this is simple one line duplicate, but when rendering the content based on state, the duplication of HTML generation logic is more serious.

I understand that in Elm union types can carry a different "payload" and the compiler does not like the generic version, but in case such as this is there some way to tell the compiler that all these cases are handling the same record type?

Or is this a case of invalid use of union types and the model should be structured differently? Maybe with the state being part of the record type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is this a case of invalid use of union types and the model should be structured differently?

If all the three variants will always contain the same data, then yes.

I'd use a record at the top and create a tagged union for the "Status" of the Comment.

```
type alias Comment =
    { id : Int
    , text : String
    , status : Status
    }


type Status
    = New
    | Edited
    | Flagged
```

This will make it easy to access `id` and `text` of a comment. You'll still get the benefits exhaustive pattern matching if you do `case comment.status of ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You could factor out the *get content* part

```
type Comment = New Content | Edited Content | Flagged Content

type alias Content = {id: Int, text: String}

filter : Int -> Comment -> Bool
filter id comment =
  let content = commentContent comment
  in  content.id == id

commentContent : Comment -> Content
commentContent comment =
  case comment of
    New content -> content
    Edited content -> content
    Flagged content -> content
```

You can abstract even further, for example if you want to add a text filter

```
filter : Int -> Comment -> Bool
filter id comment =
  doFilter (\c -> c.id == id) comment

filterText : String -> Comment -> Bool
filterText text comment =
  doFilter (\c -> c.text == text) comment

doFilter : (Content -> Bool) -> Comment -> Bool
doFilter f comment =
  let content = commentContent comment
  in  f content
```

And finally, add some functional style...

```
doFilter : (Content -> Bool) -> Comment -> Bool
doFilter f = f << commentContent
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is an excellent approach, but in my case I decided to restructure the model as Dogbert suggested in his answer. Mainly because the restructured model makes it easier to implement sorting for example.